# Is there a more elegant way to implement an modification to save() method when using CreateView and ModelForm in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, modelform, django-generic-views

I'm learning the Class-Based View and ModelForm of Django, and I feel so confused with those things.
I want to create a page where users can post articles.
My implementation is as following:

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, null=False, max_length=20)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    content = models.TextField()
    count_like = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField()
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update last_modified '''
        if not self.id:
            count = Post.objects.count()
            self.id = "PO" + str(count)
            self.created_time = timezone.now()
        self.last_modified = timezone.now()
        return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        print("pk"*100, self.pk)
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['content']
    
    def save(self):
        return super().save(commit=False)
```

views.py

```
class PostCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name="post/create.jinja"
        
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        self.object.owner = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

urlpatterns

```
path('create/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name="post_create")
```

I checked and this works.
As you can see, the `Post model` has many attributes, but I just want users to fill 1 field `content`, the others would be automatically initiated. Is there any way to improve my implementation, because it's seperated into many places (model save() method, form save() method, valid_form() method).
One more question is what is `self.object` role? After assigned to a `Post model` instance, what would it be used for?
Please help me, if you don't understand what I say please ask in comment. Thanks ^^

Comment: is there a reason why you redefining ID field. If not explicitly mentioned it would be created by Django, and you would not need to get the count of objects every time

Comment: @tessie I want it for further implementation, and I think it's not a big problem in question context right?

Comment: @KhaiHoanPham I agree with what tessie said above you don't appear to need to override the save method. Firstly "PO1", "PO2", ... can't you simply just represent that by the automatic primary key? It autoincrements and you can simply do something like `f"PO{self.pk}"` and return this in a method which you make a property. Also for `timezone.now()` you can simply set a function to default on the field so `default=timezone.now`...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat ok I will check it. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @KhaiHoanPham also check [auto_now and auto_now_add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#datefield) (the link is for datefield but it is same for datetimefield etc.)